# ¿Cómo saco los mensajes iniciales del terminal en VSCode?

Tags: java, vscode, terminal

estoy empezando a programar Java en VSCode y tengo una incomodidad respecto al terminal; al ejecutar el codigo y mostrar los resultados en la terminal, esta me muestra mensajes iniciales que me incomodan bastante a la vista:

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

Prueba la nueva tecnología PowerShell multiplataforma https://aka.ms/pscore6

(Y aquí me muestra muchas direcciones que no creo necesarias, como la ubicación del JDK y otras cosas)

Si alguien tiene idea de como sacar todas estas líneas del terminal le agradecería mucho.